# Python: SQLite3 Retrieving data as bytes and unable to convert

Tags: python, sql, pandas, database, sqlite

I am trying to understand SQLite3 by playing with storage and retrieval of dictionaries. Tutorials everywhere indicate that I should just get data back as integers (as it was entered) but I keep getting an "undecodable" byte string:

`>>> ['\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00', '\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00', '\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'] (b'\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00', b'\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00', b'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00')`

What am I missing?

```
import json
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

path_prefix = "..."

test_dict = {'A': [1,2,3],
             'B': [3,2,1],
             'C': [2,1,3]}

obj = open(path_prefix+"json_file.json", "w")
json.dump(test_dict, obj, indent=4)
obj.close()

connection = sqlite3.connect(path_prefix+'db.sqlite', detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES)
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('Create Table if not exists Test (A integer, B integer, C integer)')

content = json.loads(open(path_prefix+'json_file.json').read())

test_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(content)
print(test_df)

for i in range(len(test_df)):
    print(tuple(test_df.iloc[i].values))
    cursor.execute('insert into Test values(?,?,?)', tuple(test_df.iloc[i].values))

connection.commit()

cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Test')
print([t.decode() for t in cursor.fetchone()])
print(cursor.fetchone())

connection.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work using `connection.row_factory = sqlite3.Row` then:

```
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print(row[1])            
    print(row['A'])
```

Comment: I'll give reward answer to someone who can explain why this works but original solution doesn't